# Get text between two points in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I have an HTML page viewed in an HTML5 compatible browser on a touch-enabled device (eg- Google Chrome on Jelly Bean). I need to write a javascript such that when I touch on the screen at a point and drag my finger to another point, the text between the two points needs to be stored in a variable. How to do that? JQuery will also do.

Ask any questions if not clear.

Comment: Is `window.getSelection()` not sufficient for any reason?

Comment: I tried moving my finger on text on Windows 8 Tablet but the text isn't selected as it would with a Mouse.

Comment: So your problem isn't with how to get the text selection with javascript, it is how to make a text selection on Windows 8?

Comment: I am OK with text selection with javascript (I want to make it cross-platform specifically mobiles and tablets). But if the text doesn't get selected on device itself, how will window.getSelection() work?

Comment: Look at this link for info on how to select text: http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/windows-8-review,3334-10.html  I am honestly not that familiar with Windows 8 tablets, but my guess is that `getSelection()` will be supported. You just need to know how to select the text, which is not a programming problem, by a user problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you mark the text you can get it into a variable by using window.getSelection().toString()

Comment: I tried moving my finger on text on Windows 8 Tablet but the text isn't selected as it would with a Mouse.

Comment: Using getSelection().toString() gets all of the selected text, but how do I get only the first line of the selected text when the text is in a div where the text content has been wrapped onto multiple line when the div is rendered?